# Why does a USB Adapter set to monitor mode on Linux not capture non-WiFi traffic send on the same frequency (2.4GHz) as WiFi ?

Tags: wireshark, kali-linux, tcpip, protocol

I have a WiFi Adapter from Alfa that can function in Monitor mode on Linux. Once I set it up and run Wireshark, I am able to see traffic across other routers and devices. If there is a new protocol that uses the same 2.4GHz to transfer data, but it is not following the traditional tcp/ip protocol (like the 3-way handshake), can I still monitor it on my Alfa Adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not TCP, but it *is* Wi-Fi, you should be able to capture it; the capturing is done at the link layer, so it should see all Wi-Fi traffic that it can receive.  It can capture UDP traffic (which has no 3-way handshake), and it can even capture non-IP traffic.

If it's *not* Wi-Fi traffic - i.e., some other form of networking that happens to use a 2.4 GHz radio, but that doesn't conform to any of the PHYs from the IEEE 802.11 standard - you won't be able to monitor it with a Wi-Fi adapter, because it's not Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

@Guy Harris is largely correct, except the answer ignores extensions to the WIFI protocol in future - So, hypothetically, if your USB card was an 802.11g card, but other people were using 802.11n, the USB card would not be able to pick up perfectly valid WIFI tranmissions from the faster device, because it can't see the data flow.

So, if there is a new software protocol the hardware should be able to handle it, but if there is a newer version of the 802.11 standard which requires hardware upgrades then no.